# SSIS Can run from Visual Studio but cannot run when deployed to SQL Integration Catalog and Run Via SQL Agent

Tags: ssis, sql-server-data-tools, sql-agent, ssdt-2017

I have issue with SQL Agent
when i run it from Visual Studio SSDT its run smoothly
[image]

No data error and rum based on flow

but when i deployed it to SQL Integration Service Catalog and run via SQL Agent the job successfully done, but no data or query executed into tables.

I already used SSDT2012, 2017 and 2019 but the issue are same

Comment: Did you try executing it directly from Integration Services Catalogue?

Comment: @UmairRamzan yes i tried execute from Catalg only 0.9 sec to success but nothing happen with the table

Comment: Make sure your project debug runtime environment in 32 bit. You check this on project properties in SSIS. I had a similar type of issue with runtime.

Comment: What does your SSIS execution say in the SSIS All Executions Report? Any warnings / messages? Furthermore it seems you are working with files (ExportToFlat, ImportToDb) - which directories are you referencing? e.g. if you read files from C:\Temp this can be processed during execution in VS but not during execution in the SSIS catalog.